# Can't choose the pattern I should pursue

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm seriously confused about putting a line in my scraper in it's right position. I'm trying to use python in combination with selenium defining 10 seconds of explicit wait. However, i'm pasting the two for your consideration to tell me which one I should pursue and why? (don't overlook the commented out line in two scripts)

This is what I tried with:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)   ##Notice this line having been placed before "get"
driver.get(some_url)

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "some_selector")))
driver.quit()
```

This is another:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(some_url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)   ##Notice this line having been placed after "get"

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "some_selector")))
driver.quit()
```

Comment: I suggest trying both and using whichever one works. Should only take about 20 seconds of testing ;-)

Comment: I tried with both of them on a particular site and found response that is why i'm not sure which one to follow.

Comment: Are you trying to rate-limit your requests to an API?  Is this whole thing going to be wrapped in a `while` loop?  If so, why do you think the ordering of these two statements matter?

Comment: So you're saying that both ways work? In that case, it sounds like the ordering of the lines is a stylistic concern rather than a practical one. Then the answer of which approach is better becomes subjective. You might prefer the first one if you like to have all of your variable assignments close together at the top of your function. Or you might prefer the second one if you like to have your variable assignments as close as possible to the first time that value is used. It's up to you.

Comment: As long as you work single threaded, the sequence won't matter in this case. Not that the wait you are declaring isn't used till the next step. So it doesn't matter where you declare it. For as far as guidelines go at where I work, we declare everything first (if possible) and then we define the actions

Comment: Sorry, if my question hurts. I'm just a newbie in web-scraping so can't figure out which pattern i should stick to. This is it. Thanks.

Comment: All of you are so helpful and yes I've got my question answered already. Thanks a trillion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at both of your code blocks its pretty much evident both will have identical effects.

Through `wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)` we are creating an instance of `WebDriverWait` with the intended `webdriver` instance i.e. `driver` and the `timespan` as 2 arguments. This `wait` doesn't comes into force until & unless you explicitly use them in your code as :

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "some_selector")))
```

So, where ever you invoke the instance of the `WebDriverWait` i.e `wait`, the intended function is performed/executed irrespective of its position in the code block. In this case the function is searching for `expected_conditions` as `presence_of_element_located`.

Moreover, once you create an instance of `WebDriverWait`, e.g. `wait`, you can also use them as many times you wish (considering the arguments i.e webdriver instance and timespan are similar) in your code block as follows:

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "some_selector")))
#some code for some task
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "some_other_selector")))
#some other code for some other task
wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "some_selector_else")))
```

Comment: Thanks for your descriptive answer.